# Estilos dinámicos en un campo de Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Tengo un campo personalizado en la vista de listado de Django Admin. Lo que quiero es que si el valor de uno de los datos de la tabla es mayor a 7 ese campo tenga un reborde rojo.

Esta es la función con la que armo el campo:

```py
    def proximo(self, obj):

        last_send = obj.last_send
        if last_send:
            today = date.today()
            pass_days = (today - last_send.date()).days

            reminder = int(obj.reminder_days)
            
            dias = reminder - pass_days
            if dias >= 0:
                return dias
            else:
                return "Estamos atrasados"
        else:
            return "Today is a great day"
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resaltar un campo en la interfaz de administración de Django según el valor de un campo, puedes personalizar la apariencia utilizando JS y CSS.

1. Crea un archivo JavaScript personalizado en la carpeta static de tu
   aplicación Django. Puedes llamarlo admin_script.js o cualquier otro
   nombre que prefieras.
2. Abre el archivo JavaScript personalizado y agrega el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.field-status');
      rows.forEach(function(row) {
        var value = row.textContent.trim();
        if (value === 'inactivo') {
          row.parentElement.style.boxShadow = 'inset 1pt 1pt 11pt 1pt red'; // Color rojo para el valor "inactivo"
        } else if (value === 'activo') {
          row.parentElement.style.boxShadow = 'inset 1pt 1pt 11pt 1pt green'; // Color verde para el valor "activo"
        }
      });
    });
```

3. En tu archivo admin.py de la aplicación Django, agrega una clase
   Media a tu modelo administrativo para incluir el archivo JavaScript
   personalizado. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    
    class Media:
        js = ('path/to/admin_script.js',)
```